# Calculation on cash opname form with jquery

Tags: jquery

The Cash Opname Form

```
<form action="" id="frm_cash_opname" name="frm_cash_opname" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 text-left">KERTAS</div>                            
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">100,000</div>                          
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="J1" name="J1" data-nilai="100000" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="T1" name="T1" value="0" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 text-left">KERTAS</div>                            
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">50,000</div>                           
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="J2" name="J2" data-nilai="50000" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="T2" name="T2" value="0" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 text-left"><b>TOTAL</b></div>                          
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right"></div>                         
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right"></div>                         
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
            <input type="text" id="TOTAL" name="TOTAL" class="form-control number" dir="rtl" readonly="readonly">
        </div>                          
    </div>

</form>
```

I want to make calculation based on this requirement :

```
sub_total = $( "input[name^='J']" ) * data-nilai )
```

And output in each sub total, identified by The ID :

```
$("input[name^='T']")
```

And also calculate all total in all rows, Sum of Total :

```
 $( "input[name^='T']" ) )
```

And output it in :

```
$( "input[name='TOTAL']" )
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English

Comment: So where is the question?

Comment: sorry for not clear. i want to output each subtotal ( $("#input[name^='J' ") ) in every row. and also automatically update the total in the last div ($("#TOTAL"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `each()` method :

```
$('#calc').click(function(){
    var total = 0;

    $('form').find(".form-group:not(:last)").each(function(){
      var j_field = parseInt($("input[name^='J']", this).val());
      var j_field_nilai = parseInt($("input[name^='J']", this).data('nilai'));
      var sub_total = j_field*j_field_nilai;

      $("input[name^='T']", this).val(sub_total);
      total+= sub_total;
    })

    $( "input[name='TOTAL']" ).val(total);
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#calc').click(function(){
  var total = 0;

  $('form').find(".form-group:not(:last)").each(function(){
    var j_field = parseInt($("input[name^='J']", this).val());
    var j_field_nilai = parseInt($("input[name^='J']", this).data('nilai'));
    var sub_total = j_field*j_field_nilai;
    
    $("input[name^='T']", this).val(sub_total);
    total+= sub_total;
  })

  $( "input[name='TOTAL']" ).val(total);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="frm_cash_opname" name="frm_cash_opname" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 text-left">KERTAS</div>                            
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">100,000</div>                          
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="J1" name="J1" data-nilai="100000" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="T1" name="T1" value="0" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 text-left">KERTAS</div>                            
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">50,000</div>                           
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="J2" name="J2" data-nilai="50000" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="T2" name="T2" value="0" class="form-control number" dir="rtl">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 text-left"><b>TOTAL</b></div>                          
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right"></div>                         
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right"></div>                         
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
            <input type="text" id="TOTAL" name="TOTAL" class="form-control number" dir="rtl" readonly="readonly">
        </div>                          
    </div>

</form>

<button id='calc'>Calculate</button>
```

Comment: thanks. it works great ! except i couldn't get the Total.
`i try console.log(total). The result is NaN`

Comment: Thanks. in my case i have to edit it a little.

$("input[name^='T']", this).val(sub_total);
var tempvar = (isNaN(sub_total)) ? 0 : sub_total;    
total += tempvar;